# How to recover ebs from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Given a cloudformation template with an EC2 instance that uses a EBS volume defined as follows:

```
  DefaultVolume:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
      Size: 8
      Tags:
        -
          Key: Name
          Value: Jenkins
      VolumeType: gp2
```

How can I set up the cloudformation template so when I recreate the stack again (after a deletion and ebs snapshot created), the ebs recovers the data from the snapshot instead of creating a brand new volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to reference a snapshot of a deleted stack. One issue with that is how would it know which snapshot to take if there are multiple stacks created from the same template?

What you can do is add a parameter for your template for the snapshot id and use it with `SnapshotId` when specified.

```
Parameters:
  OldSnapshot:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
Conditions:
  OldSnapshotAvailable:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref OldSnapshot, ""]]
Resources:
  DefaultVolume:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
      Size: 8
      Tags:
        -
          Key: Name
          Value: Jenkins
      VolumeType: gp2
      SnapshotId: !If [OldSnapshotAvailable, !Ref OldSnapshot, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
```

Comment: > I'm not sure there is a way to reference a snapshot of a deleted stack. One issue with that is how would it know which snapshot to take if there are multiple stacks created from the same template?
You could use the env variable `${AWS::StackName}`

Comment: What if there are multiple deleted versions of the same stack name?

Comment: Does the snapshot you want have any tags that can help you find it? If so, you can script that and pass the result as a parameter. You can also put that logic in a custom resource.